# ng-repeat adding conditional coding struggling with making the change

Tags: angularjs, vbscript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I’ve been living in an old school Classic ASP using VBScript. I’ve recently jumped into the AngularJS world head first,  along with JQuery and Ajax worlds... it's all incredibly exciting. I'm quickly falling in love with Angular, since a lot of what i do is build reports, thank you ng-repeat. Now, I know Ajax is effectively built into AngularJS and I’ve been told to forget about JQuery and I should leave my VBScript days behind me. ya, this is a little tough but I’m getting’ there.

I'm trying to figure out how to add conditional code to a list.

I would normally cycle through a record set checking for specific conditions while adding functionality through the use of sub routines and functions to qualified cells of data as I traverse my way through it all. I suspect it’s not the right thing to do in this new world but I think it’s safe to say, I’m a bit of an old school scripter / hack… I can now appreciate that I need to change my perspective and evolve, which I have been doing.

With that said, if I have…

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat=”item in myList”>
    <td>{{item.field1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.field2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

At what point would I be able to start adding in conditional functionality? Let’s say…

```
If item.field2 > item.filed3 then
    add function of sorts in the fourth column
else
    add a class to the tr
end if
```

well, there you have it. my first post on this awesome site. Please be kind and help and old brain get with the times. ;-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, your question is a quite broad. Usually data is processed using a service or a controller. View-specific changes, like a class, can use directives such as [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Can you clarify how this data is generated?

Comment: I suspect it’s a little “broad” because I don’t know the correct term to use ;-/

i'm pulling JSON formatted data via http.get('scripts/Fetch_Matches.asp?… blah, blah...).success(function(data) {
scope.MatchesFound = data;    
});    

The asp page is making a call to our SQL server collecting and formatting the data accordingly. What I have noticed is that I need to put some effort into areas that aren’t obvious to me. I’m noticing if I spend more time refining my stored procedures, doing some of the decision making at that level, then it makes other downstream decisions easier.

Answer (score 1):

To add conditional CSS classes you can use the ngClass.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

If you want to show the results of a function in the 4th column. You can assign a function to the `scope`.

```
 scope.doStuff = function(item) {
     return item.field4;
 }
```

Here's how it would look in the HTML.

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat=”item in myList” ng-class="{itemCss:item.field2 <= item.field3}">
     <td>{{item.field1}}</td>
     <td>{{item.field2}}</td>
     <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
     <td>{{doStuff(item)}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: that's cool! so i could assign the function and build all my conditional stuff within? that looks like it might be exactly what i'm looking for! Thanks so much ;-)